# \n not working in php code when using chrome browser

Tags: php

I am using the \n to insert a new line when echoing a string in PHP. But the output does not seem to reflect this. I am using chrome browser to display the output.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
echo "Developers, Developers, developers, developers,\n developers,
developers, developers, developers, developers!";
?>
```

I expect the output to be:

Developers, Developers, developers, developers,
developers, developers, developers, developers, developers!

But it is being displayed in a single line in chrome as:

Developers, Developers, developers, developers, developers, developers, 
developers, developers, developers!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Ydi.jpg

Comment: try `\r\n` to lb? Or, better yet, replace `\n` with `PHP_EOL`

Comment: @treyBake still not working

Comment: Do you mean in your rendered page or in your source code? `\n` will only work in the page source, not in the rendered HTML output

Comment: @kerbholz in my rendered page; see the image

Comment: @kerbholz yes it is working in the page source; but why does it not work in the rendered page?

Comment: @Steveaustin did you concat when you used `PHP_EOL`?

Comment: Because you use `<br>` as a new line in HTML output. (If you want to keep that `\n` in your string but have a new line in HTML, take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: @kerbholz <br> does work, but then what is the use of \n in PHP echo statements; also when using the <<< operator in multiline output statements the indentation are being ignored

Comment: PHP can also be used at the command line, that's where `\n` would work as a newline. Or to nicely format your HTML source code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in HTML new-line characters are effectively ignored when rendering output.

To insert a line-break, just replace your new-line characters `\n` with the HTML equivalent, `<br />`.

In your code example, this would be:

```
<?php 
echo "Developers, Developers, developers, developers,<br /> developers,
developers, developers, developers, developers!";
?>
```